# flutter app release showing an error Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, visual-studio-code

I am new to flutter and i tried release my app .

The flutter is building the apk in debug mode

```
buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
   }
```

}

when i change it into release  like this

```
buildTypes {
   release {
       signingConfig signingConfigs.release
   }
```

}

it is showing Like this

PS C:\Users\Ravi\FlutterProjects\tictactoe> flutter build apk --release
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to
reduce the APK size.
To generate an app bundle, run:
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
To split the APKs per ABI, run:
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-splitRunning Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Removed unused resources: Binary resource data reduced from 101KB to 96KB: Removed 5%
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

- What went wrong:
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Ravi\FlutterProjects\tictactoe\android\app\c:UsersRavikey.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.
> Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

- Try:
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
  Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
BUILD FAILED in 6m 6s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     374.9s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS C:\Users\Ravi\FlutterProjects\tictactoe> flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64, android-x64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to
reduce the APK size.
To generate an app bundle, run:
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
To split the APKs per ABI, run:
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 --split-per-abi
Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-splitregisterResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.

> Keystore file 'C:\Users\Ravi\FlutterProjects\tictactoe\android\app\c:UsersRavikey.jks' not found for signing config 'release'.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 12s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                      13.8s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
PS C:\Users\Ravi\FlutterProjects\tictactoe>

Comment: can you check and see if your path is correct. It seems it is not.

Comment: storePassword = ******
keyPassword = ******
keyAlias = TicTacToe
storeFile = c:\Users\Ravi\key.jks

Comment: Ihave added internet permissions in Androidmanifest.xml file

Comment: Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore c:\Users\Ravi\key.jks -destkeystore c:\Users\Ravi\key.jks -deststoretype pkcs12".
PS C:\Users\Ravi\FlutterProjects\tictactoe>

Comment: i just changed the keyAlias to key   Same error is appearing

Comment: [can you follow these steps](https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-sign-and-release-your-flutter-app-ed5e9531c2ac) . I have published all my apps using this

Answer (score 0):

**for release you need sign your app.**
**Create an upload keystore**
[for more detials please visit offical documents](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29818621)