# Why am I unable to build a signed bundle release in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-play, build.gradle, android-keystore, android-app-bundle

I'm trying to make app bundle with the help of [flutter doc](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android) by running `Flutter build appbundle --release` but I always get this error:

> Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningRelease'.
> Keystore file 'C:\Users\MY_NAME\FlutterProjects\gym\android\app\Users\MY_NAME\key.jks'
> not found for signing config 'release'.

I already tried many approaches answered by others [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60233117/execution-failed-for-task-appvalidatesigningrelease-flutter-error), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63336398/flutter-app-release-showing-an-error-execution-failed-for-task-appvalidatesig) and many others but none helpful for me.

I used this command to build keystore

`C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore C:\Users\MY_NAME\FlutterProjects\gym\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key`

and file saved in that path `C:\Users\MY_NAME`

**My build.gradle looks like this:**

```
...


def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
   keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

...

 signingConfigs {
       release {
           keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
           keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
           storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
           storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }

...

signingConfig signingConfigs.release
```

P.S: I even put **key.properties** file under `/android` and under `/android/app` with below propertise
but results are same as above error

```
storePassword=MY_PWD
keyPassword=MY_PWD
keyAlias=key
storeFile=/Users/MY_NAME/key.jks
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try giving complete path in key.properties file. i.e.

```
storePassword=MY_PWD
keyPassword=MY_PWD
keyAlias=key
storeFile=C:/Users/MY_NAME/key.jks
```

Comment: I tried with this path too but still same.

Comment: please use the full path for storeFile and put the error that you get after running  flutter build appbundle --release in comment

Comment: Idk how is it worked coz I also had tried with full path before. But it worked this time. Thanks to you!